# Plot mix of dirac and empirical distributions in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks a bit like this:

```
myData <- data.frame(dist1=rep(0.5, 1000), dist2=rnorm(1000,0.8,0.01), dist3=rnorm(1000,0.7,0.05))
```

Note that dist1 consists exclusively of the number 0.5.

**Question: How would you plot this data using ggplot in R?**

**My failed attempts:**

If I try geom_density then it doesn't do justice to dist1:

```
ggplot(melt(myData), aes(x=value, colour=variable)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

I know I can tune the kernel width, but as dist1 becomes pointy, dist2 and dist3 start to break up
[image]

If I try geom_freqpoly then it automatically selects the bin boundaries and causes the dist1 peak to be to one side of 0.5, confusing the reader that expects it to be bang-on 0.5:

```
ggplot(melt(myData), aes(x=value, colour=variable)) + geom_freqpoly()
```

[image]

I know I can change the bin widths, but not the bin divisions themselves, otherwise I'd make sure there were bin divisions equidistant either side of 0.5.

Comment: I think your big problem with `dist1` is that you're forcing the plot to create a line when in fact you should be plotting points.  No matter what you do, unless the distribution (x-axis values) of `dist1` is extremely fine, the line will plot from 0.5 to the next points in the dataset.  Try just plotting points, or creating a 2Xn matrix `fakedist1` which has ordered pairs (0.5,0);(0.5,1000),(0.5,0) in it and plot as a plain old line.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the suggestions. For plotting points do you mean like geom_dotplot?  Presumably the line suggestion would amount to drawing a line (dist1) on top of the smooth density plots (dists 2 & 3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to manipulate the bins by using stat_bin with line geom, rather than geom_freqpoly.  Seems to give a much improved and tunable result:

```
ggplot(melt(myData), aes(x=value, colour=variable)) + 
  stat_bin(origin = 0.491, binwidth = 0.006, geom='line', position='identity')
```

[image]